# Script defer doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript

I have the following test to see whether the `defer` attribute defers execution of script block.  There are 2 script blocks.  1st one with the `defer` attribute and 2nd one with out.  If I understand correctly, the attribute forces the browser to execute the block when all html parsing has been completed (including the other `script` block).

But looking at the console, I always the 'from deferred' first.  Why is that?  Does `defer` not work on the local `script` blocks?

```
<html>
<body>
   ...

  <script type="text/javascript" defer>
    console.log('from deferred');
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('from regular');
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**[`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)** only works on **external** scripts:

> This attribute must not be used if the `src` attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.
>
> To achieve a similar effect for dynamically inserted scripts use `async=false` instead. Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.

Also,

> Scripts without `async` or `defer` attributes, as well as inline scripts, are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page.

Because local scripts are executed before the page finishes parsing, `defer` will not apply. `defer` gets applied **after** parsing, but **before** **[DomContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)**.